# Paypal UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE

Tags: paypal, fetch

I am trying to get an access token from paypal's authorization api.
When I make post request to the api I get `UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE` i.e. 415 response.

Below is the snippet that I used.

```
const auth = await fetch(PAYPAL_OAUTH_API, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Basic ${ basicAuth }`
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({"grant_type": "client_credentials"})
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have fixed my issue by setting `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

My guess is paypal accepts only `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for authorization api.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into same issue, and the solution is following (using Postman):

1. Select POST
2. Add `Token` into `Authorization`, type is Bearer-Token
3. Select `Content-Type: application/json` in headers
4. Use `RAW` as body, and in `TEXT` dropdown, select JSON (`application/JSON`)
5. Copy body as raw object and change info accordingly.

Step 4 and 5 are what solved the error, you must send raw json object.

Comment: Thanks this sorted my issue!

Comment: Great, glad to help @JamieBurke

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74363765/paypal-integration-with-laravel-using-v2-php-sdk